# Access Query for Last X Records based on Distinct Field

Tags: ms-access, distinct

I have an access database with a table that contains the following fields: `EntryID`, `MaterialNumber`

```
EntryID  MaterialNumber
1        123
2        124
3        125
4        125
5        126
```

I'm try to write a query that will return the last 3 distinct material numbers.

```
MaterialNumber
126
125
124
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 MaterialNumber 
FROM (SELECT EntryID, MaterialNumber FROM Table1 ORDER BY EntryID DESC);
```

I get:

```
126
125
125
```

When I add `DISTINCT` into the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 MaterialNumber 
FROM (SELECT EntryID, MaterialNumber FROM Table1 ORDER BY EntryID DESC);
```

I get (Not the first three entries but the three lowest entries):

```
123
124
125
```

Can anyone help develop a query and explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This threw me too - I think Access is re-sorting the data when you run select distinct.  In MySQL I believe you could just order by ID desc and group by the materialnumber but not ID, but I haven't tested it.  But for Access here's one way

```
Select materialnumber from (
Select top 3 max(entryid), materialnumber from table1 
group by materialnumber order by max(entryid) desc)
```

Comment: Works Great!  I was struggling with why adding the Distinct keyword resorted the data.  Thank you very much for the solution.